# Finding the limit of a sequence of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity

Take any $\bar{r} \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\bar{r}>0$.

Assume that $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is continuous.

Assume that for all $r\in [0,\bar{r})$, there exists a *strictly decreasing* real sequence $\{t(r)^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that

> $t(r)^1 = r$,

and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}\backslash\{1\}$,

> $ 0 < t(r)^n < r, \qquad$    (1)

and

> $f\big(t(r)^n\big) - f\big(t(r)^{n-1}\big) \geq 0. \qquad$    (2)

**Question** : is it possible to have $f(0) < f(\bar{r})$ or does it necessarily induce a contradiction?

What I have done so far:

- I have tried to work by contradiction, assuming that $f(0) < f(\bar{r})$ holds.
- Because $t(\bar{r})^n$ is bounded by (1), it has a converging subsequence, say $t(\bar{r})^{m(n)} \rightarrow r^*_1$.
- We know from (1) and the fact that the sequence is strictly decreasing that $0 \leq r^*_1 < \bar{r}$.
- Using (2) repeatedly together with the continuity of $f$, we get $f(r^*_1) - f(\bar{r}) \geq 0$.
- Then by the contradiction assumption we obtain $f(r^*_1) > f(0)$.
- If $r^*_1 = 0$, we reached a contradiction and we are done.
- Otherwise, we can repeat the process again and again, getting $0 \leq r^*_2 < r^*_1$, $0 \leq r^*_3 < r^*_2$, ...
- But I do not see why we would necessarily reach some $r^*_{n}$ such that  $r^*_{n}=0$. Is it the case? Are their counterexamples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to assume that for every $r \in [0, \overline{r})$, there exists $0 < r' < r$ such that $f(r') \geq f(r)$. Suppose, towards a contradiction, $f(\overline{r}) > f(0)$. Since $f$ is continuous at $\overline{r}$, we can find some $0 < r_1 < \overline{r}$ such that $f(r_1) > f(0)$. Let $r_0 = \text{inf } \{r \in [0, r_1) : f(r) \geq f(r_1)\}$. Since $f$ is continuous at $r_0$, $f(r_0) \geq f(r_1)$ so $r_0 > 0$. But your assumption implies that for some $0 < r' < r_0$, $f(r') \geq f(r_0) \geq f(r_1)$: A contradiction to the minimality of $r_0$.

Comment: Great answer, many thanks.